# How to use JSON.NET's JsonTextReader to read from a NetworkStream asynchronously?

Tags: c#, silverlight, json.net

I implemented my own `NetworkStream` port for Silverlight which only allows asynchronous calls.
I would like to read some JSON-RPC messages that I am getting from a server so I figured I'd use JSON.NET `JsonTextReader` so I ended up with the following code:

```
reader = new JsonTextReader(new StreamReader(new NetworkStream(new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))));  
// ...
reader.Read();
```

My problem is that it will attempt to perform a synchronous operation which in turn just throw `UnsupportedException`.
Is there an asynchronous `StreamReader` that I can feed the `JsonTextReader` with?
Should I take another approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should. I don't think you can force JsonTextReader to use async approach, but you could modify the entire method used for getting data to behave asynchronously. Also, use

```
using(var io = new StreamReader())
{ 
    io.Read(); 
}
```

syntax.

Comment: I know that I should be using the 'using' syntax. It wasn't relevant to the question. Thanks anyway.